# Setting the OperationTimeOut property for a Service bus worker role

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-worker-roles, servicebus

I am creating a worker role using the service bus worker role template.

It is taking more than a minute for me to process each message.

Because of this, i am seeing that the same message is received by the worker role multiple times, roughly one message every minute.

I figured that this is because this value defaults to 60 seconds.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagingfactorysettings.operationtimeout.aspx

But I am not sure how to increase this value, because i am not seeing the messageFactorySettings class anywhere.

Where do I set this property?

here is the code I am using

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {

        // QueueClient is thread-safe. Recommended that you cache 
        // rather than recreating it on every request
        QueueClient Client;
        ManualResetEvent CompletedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public override void Run()
        {

            Client.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
                {
                    ProcessMessage(recievedMessage);
                });

            CompletedEvent.WaitOne();
        }

        public override bool OnStart()
        {
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

            string connectionString = ConfigurationUtility.GetConnectionString("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
            string queneName = ConfigurationUtility.GetConnectionString("QueueName");

            // Create the queue if it does not exist already
            var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
            if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists(queneName))
            {
                namespaceManager.CreateQueue(queneName);

            }

            Client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queneName);
            return base.OnStart();
        }

        public override void OnStop()
        {
            // Close the connection to Service Bus Queue
            Client.Close();
            CompletedEvent.Set();
            base.OnStop();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the ConnectionStringBuilder which is easier to use than creating the necessary address for MessagingFactory by yourself:

```
var builder = new  ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(_connectionString)
{
OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2) 
};

var messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(builder.ToString());
var queueClient = MessagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(_queuePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, you need to use the `MessagingFactory` class to do this.

I've just written the following to increase the timeout to 2 mins:

```
MessagingFactorySettings settings = new MessagingFactorySettings { 
                OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0), 
                TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider("issuer", "sharedkey") };

var address = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", "serviceNamespace", string.Empty);

var messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.Create(address, settings);

return messagingFactory.CreateSubscriptionClient("queueName");
```