# Setting OperationTimeout in Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.TopicClient

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I would like to add OperationTimeout to TopicClient.
The old code looks like:

```
var newTopicClient = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(
                         serviceBusSenderConnectionString,
                         topicName);
```

Other example I found need to use MessagingFactory([Setting the OperationTimeOut property for a Service bus worker role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416435/setting-the-operationtimeout-property-for-a-service-bus-worker-role)).

I wonder if I can do it like:

```
ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder serviceBusSenderConnectionStringBuilder = 
    new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(serviceBusSenderConnectionString)
        {
            OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)
        };

        var newTopicClient =  TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(
                                  serviceBusSenderConnectionStringBuilder.ToString(),
                                  topicName);
```

Or shall I

```
newTopicClient.MessagingFactory.GetSettings().OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
```

Dose this affect all service bus operation? What if I only want to set timeout for SendAsync()? IS this example(https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/crafting-a-task-timeoutafter-method/) the only option?

Comment: From the docs, suppose they all could be used to set the `OperationTimeout ` property. [ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.servicebusconnectionstringbuilder.operationtimeout?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder_OperationTimeout) and [MessagingFactorySettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagingfactorysettings.operationtimeout?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_MessagingFactorySettings_OperationTimeout).